# Azure B2C - Ap.Net WebForms(No MVC) - AuthorizationCodeReceived

Tags: azure, session, caching, webforms, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement the

> Azure B2C authentication with Asp.Net WebForms(NO MVC)

But I am not sure how to store the AuthenticationTicket in the AuthorizationCodeReceived section.

I am following the sample from 
[Azure B2C Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi)

[Sample Code using MVC](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi)

The Problem is when I am following the Sample Code in the

> MSALSessionCache.cs

```
 public void Load()
    {            
        SessionLock.EnterReadLock();

        //context.Session[CacheId] is always Null            
         cache.Deserialize((byte[])context.Session[CacheId]);

        SessionLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
```

The context.Session[CacheId] is always Null. Please help me to fix the same.
Thanks.